# distortion in loading dots animation after showing it again

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

I'm using TweenMax(the older version of gasp) to animate a simple loading dots:

```js
function hideDots(){
    const dots = document.querySelector('.dotContainer');
    dots.style.opacity = 0; 
    dots.addEventListener('transitionend', hideDotsAnime);
    function hideDotsAnime() {
        dots.style.display = "none";
        dots.removeEventListener("transitionend", hideDotsAnime);
    }
}

function showDots(){
    TweenMax.staggerTo(".dots",2,{x:220,backgroundColor:'white',repeat:-1,ease:SlowMo.ease.config(0.5,0.4,false)},0.4);
    TweenMax.staggerFrom(".dots",2,{opacity:0,scale:0.7,repeat:-1,ease:SlowMo.ease.config(0.5,0.4,true)},0.4);
    const dots = document.querySelector('.dotContainer');
    dots.style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(() => dots.style.opacity = 0.75, 200);
}

setTimeout(() => showDots(), 2500);

setTimeout(() => hideDots(), 5900);

setTimeout(() => showDots(), 10000);
```

```css
body{
            background-color: black
}
.dotContainer {
          background-color: transparent;
          position: absolute;
          top: 60vh;
          left: 42vw;
          transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
          display: none;
          transition: all 0.5s linear;
          z-index: 11;
}
.dots {
          position: absolute;
          width: 1em;
          height: 1em;
          border-radius: 50%;
          background-color: #e2daeb;
          opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<script SRC="https://langfox.ir/english/TweenMax.min.js" TYPE="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="dotContainer">
<div class="dots"></div>
<div class="dots"></div>
<div class="dots"></div>
<div class="dots"></div>
<div class="dots"></div>
</div>
```

As you see for the first time showing and hiding the dots works perfectly fine. but the issue is when we show the dots again distortion occurs and we don't have those beautifully animating dots anymore now they are closed to each other and...

How can I fix this?

Comment: `setTimeout(showDots, 2500);`  and you execute `dots.addEventListener('transitionend', hideDotsAnime);` every time they hide

Comment: So what?..........

Comment: Add this in the top of your showDots function `TweenMax.set(".dots", {x:0,backgroundColor:'transparent'})`

Comment: @ptothep thanks it solved one of the issues... now we have some of the dots with low opacity compared to others!

Comment: Every time you add an event listener, it does it again and again, so perhaps the hideDotsAnime is not finished and then is called again while it is in the process of trying to show again

Comment: Add this to the top `TweenMax.set(".dots", {x:0,backgroundColor:'transparent',opacity:0.8,scale:1})` i think it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much... it works now...

Comment: Why not upgrade to GSAP 3? It has a smaller file size, a sleeker API, and a *bunch* of new features. Upgrading [is easy](https://greensock.com/3-migration/).